# Error: 'for' loop declarations only in c99 mode

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement, label, declaration

I am trying to compile this C code in my linux system (I am new to all of this) and I keep getting this error:

```
ForkCall.c: In function ‘main’:
  ForkCall.c:70:1: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    ^
  ForkCall.c:70:1: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

I tried declaring int i before the for loop, but got this error:

```
ForkCall.c: In function ‘main’:
  ForkCall.c:69:1: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is 
  not a statement
   int i;

   ^
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid, pid2;
    int n;

    printf("Select a number [1-5]: ") ;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n\n");

    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
        fork();
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;

    case 2:
        fork(); fork();
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;

    case 3:
        fork(); fork(); fork();
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;

    case 4:
        if((pid=fork()) && (pid2 = fork())) {fork();}
        if((pid=fork()) && (pid2 = fork())) {fork();}
        if ((pid=fork()) && (pid2 = fork())) {fork();}
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;

    case 5:
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
            fork();
        }
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;

    default:
        printf("Number not in range [1-5] !\n");

    }
}
``
```

Comment: Did you try the helpful advice emitted by your compiler: "use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code"?

Comment: Put `int i;` at the top of the function or just above the `switch` block or put the `case` body inside `{ }`.

Comment: Please reduce the code to [mcve]. Most of the posted is irrelevant.

Comment: To understand those specific errors just google the exact error msg.

Comment: For the switch-case issue with the declaration of `int i` after the case label... that's an oddity of the language.  To get around it, you can simply put a semicolon after the label and colon to end that statement allowing you to then declare your int:

`case 5:; int i;`

Comment: As long as your apt to change it anyway it, try a C standard ratified in the most recent *decade* if your compiler supports it. I.e. -std=c11

Answer (score 1):

Either set the option of the compiler that allows to compile code as a C99 code (or C11, or C18). Or rewrite this part of the code:

```
    case 5:
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
        fork();
        }
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;
```

the following way

```
    case 5:
    {
        int i = 1;
        for ( ; i<=5; i++)
        {
            fork();
        }
        printf("This is process %d\n", getpid());
        break;
    }
```

That is, enclose the compound statement in this code snippet in braces. Then the label will not precede a declaration.